# pandas how to explode from two cells element-wise

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-munging, pandas-explode

I have a dataframe:

```
df = 
A  B  C
1 [2,3] [4,5]
```

And I want to explode it element-wise based on [B,C] to get:

```
df = 
A B  C
1 2  4
1 3  5
```

What is the best way to do so?
B and C are always at the same length.

Thanks

Comment: this has been solved multiple times. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe-into-multiple-rows/61390677#61390677)

Answer (score 1):

Try, in pandas [1.3.2](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html?highlight=explode):

```
df.explode(['B', 'C'])
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  2  4
0  1  3  5
```